# Replace content in a file or line matching a regular expression using SED

Tags: shell, unix, sed

How to replace a line / part of a line in a file using SED command?

```
search_text_1_server=value.env_1.path_to_file
search_text_2_server=value.env_1.path_to_file
search_text_3_server=value.env_1.path_to_file
some_other_key=value.env_1.another_path
```

Now I want a sed command to find the lines which match the regular expression `search_text_{any}_server and then replace env_1 with env_2`

Found the regular expression to find the required lines.

`^search_text_[a-z_]\*_server.*$`

Now how to add the SED syntax to replace

PS : I am not an expert in shell

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post what you have done and what problems you are having and we will try to help you.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I asked after doing my own research.

Comment: **Caution:** Please do not change such an old question and attempt an answer that is not even asked in your question. I suggest you to ask a new question and rollback your latest changes.

Comment: @anubhava I am not answering a question which is not asked. I am providing an answer for my own question.

Comment: @anubhava I marked your answer back, also deleted my answer. I think you can upvote my question back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is close. You can use:

```
sed -E 's/^(search_text_[a-z_]*_server=.*)env_1\./\1env_2\./' file

search_text_1_server=value.env_2.path_to_file
search_text_2_server=value.env_2.path_to_file
search_text_3_server=value.env_2.path_to_file
some_other_key=value.env_1.another_path
```

Comment: this worked. It is displaying in console the way I want

Comment: added \ to get this worked on mac terminal.  

`sed -i '' 's/^\(search_text_[1-9_]*_server=.*\)env_1\./\1env_2\./' test.txt`

Comment: `-E` works on OSX as well so `sed -i '' -E 's/^(search_text_[a-z_]*_server=.*)env_1\./\1env_2\./' file` will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming country code to be two alphabets, you could do

```
sed -Ei 's/(search_text_[a-z]{2}_server=value\.)env_1/\1env_2/' file
```

should do it.

---

**What's happening here**

1. `[a-z]{2}` checks for two alphabets which make a country code
2. sed `s` command is for substitution -> `s/pattern/replacement`
3. `()` selects the matched regex pattern for reuse, Note `\1` for reuse
4. `-i` is the inplace edit option of `sed` which makes changes permanent in the file